# sizeof C++ class from static member function

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, sizeof, member

I am attempting to write a piece of C++ code that allocates an instance of a class from within a static class member, while having it aware of the size of any inherited subclasses

.h file

```
class MyObject {
    int toastNumber;
    static MyObject *allocate();
}
class MySubclass : public MyObject {
    int NSABackdoor;
    int someOldFunction();
}
```

.cpp file

```
#include ".h file"

MyObject *MyObject::allocate() {
    return (MyObject *)calloc(1, sizeof(this)); // error here
}

int MySubclass::someOldFunction() {
    return 6;
}
```

main.cpp file

```
#include other files
int main() {
    MySubclass *instance = MySubclass::allocate();
    return 0;
}
```

Upon attempting to compile the code g++ spits out an error like

```
MyObject.cpp: In static member function ‘static MyObject* MyObject::allocate()’:
MyObject.cpp:5:47: error: ‘this’ is unavailable for static member functions
```

Can instances be allocated from within member functions like this?
I cannot just use sizeof(MyObject) because that would break inheritance. 
I know this can be done with a macro, but I would prefer it as a class function.

Thankyou

--

Kaelan

Comment: Don't use calloc in C++ (use new) and you can't use `this` in a static member function it makes no sense. `sizeof(MyObject)` will work though.

Comment: @Borgleader he is trying to get the class name from `this` not an object. But yes, doesnt work because C++ doesnt support this.

Comment: Are you by chance confusing `static` with `virtual`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on doing it like this, you should use templates, like below.

```
template <class SubClass>
static SubClass* allocate();

template <class SubClass>
SubClass *MyObject::allocate() {
    return (SubClass *)calloc(1, sizeof(SubClass));
    //or return new SubClass();  // this is better and is the C++ way
}
```

Please do note that using `calloc` will likely lead to further problems down the line, starting with the fact that it wont call the constructor.

Also I assume you meant `malloc`, since `calloc` appears to be meant for arrays.

Then you would call it as

```
MySubclass *instance = MyObject::allocate<MySubclass>();
```

Your code doesn't work because C++ doesn't have a concept of "Self Type"

Comment: The C++ way would be to not use `new` at all.

Comment: This is needlessly complicated and it uses calloc.

Comment: This is the only one that actually understood the question. -- wait, nevermind, it's not the solution I thought it was

Comment: @Borgleader read the question fully and perhaps you can see the reason for the complexity, as for the `calloc`, I typically try to fix the problem first before making further suggestions (in the next line)

Comment: Nevermind my nevermind. I was thinking more along the lines of returning a Base class pointer from the template function.  That way there will be an error if you try to call it with a class that is not a sub-class.  But I guess it depends where you want the error to be caught.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley wouldnt you then need to cast the result of the function call? It is a valid concern, I just left it for the sake of simplicity mostly. Ideally C++ should natively support such expressions like java does.. not sure if MI is part of the reason for them not adding it..

Comment: @KarthikT: Not unless you wanted to store the result in a sub-class pointer.  But if that was wanted, I have no idea why this would be a static function instead of a normal free function, since it has no relation to this hierarchy.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley that is what is happening in the question. as to why it is a static func, perhaps he has simplified it, and actually has baseclass specific stuff in it.. or he expected it to work without templates

Comment: This appears to be the closest I can get to my original intention, I did not know of templates until now.
I will leave my accepted answer here.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear. Static member functions do not belong to any specific object and can access only static data members of the class. That is a why you do not require a class instance to call static member functions.

You can try -

```
MyObject *MyObject::allocate() {
    return new MyObject();
}
```

And remember to delete the resources.

Comment: Your code works and seems to be subclass-aware. Thankyou. If I may also ask, is there a way to `subclass *i = subclass::allocate()` without casting to subclass? As ::allocate returns a MyObject.

Comment: @KaelanDuck: What do you mean by saying it's "subclass-aware"?  It's going to allocate a `MyObject` object, no matter which class it's called from.

Comment: This is not subclass aware

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I mean I can access all the members of a subclass even though I seem to be allocating a MyObject

Comment: @KaelanDuck: I don't know what code you've used to determine that, but it's wrong.

Comment: @KaelanDuck With the above solution? No. It allocates an object of base class type, *not* of subclass/derived type.

Comment: @KaelanDuck I think I didn't completely understood what you are asking in the original question. Can you please unmark the psot as accepted ?

Comment: Okay I understand what you mean now, my program was overwriting other memory locations when trying to access the subclass members, angering malloc and crashing.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use calloc, but new
Second, you can use sizeof(MyObject)
Third, even if this was avaible, sizeof(this) is a size of pointer to object, not object itself

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want to do is override `operator new` for `MyClass` and derived classes thereof:

```
class MyObject {
    int toastNumber;
    static void* operator new(std::size_t size) {
        void* ptr = ::operator new(size);
        std::cout << "Allocated " << size << " bytes at address "
                  << ptr << '\n';
        return ptr;
    }
};
```

The compiler passes the correct size of block to allocate depending on whether you're allocating an actual `MyClass` or some larger derived class. Be forewarned that it's not nearly as useful as you might think.

What do you want to do with this?